# Debugging activeX dll via classic ASP

Tags: dll, vb6, asp-classic, activex

I finally got my localhost to display the site locally.  Everything seems to be working on that end.  My next step is to actually be able to step into the code from the VB6 IDE when the web site uses a function from the ActiveX.dll

**UPDATE:**

I updated the code and removed the issue I was having compiling the code.

Now when I try to debug the site won't open.  It just hangs.  I'm wondering are there any tutorials that I can read so figure out how to properly get this application setup for debugging?

**UPDATE #2**

Just to clarify, I got the web site (which references the ActiveX .dlls) locally on IIS 7.5.  My hope is that when I open the site (on localhost) I can step through the .dll code at the same time.

That is really what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite easy.  First of all, do an `iisreset`.  Then load up Visual Basic with your ActiveX DLL.  Place your breakpoint, then Run your project.

Then hit your page containing a call to the ActiveX DLL and it should stop on a breakpoint you just set.

Comment: so...  Do I make the .dlls and put them on the server and then run my project?  Or do I leave the .dlls out and just run the vb6 project?

Comment: @Jeff, forget about the DLLs and just run the VB6 project.  Visual Basic uses a technique called COM Redirection to be able to redirect the call from the actual DLL to the VB IDE.

Comment: Oh, hold done a sec, are you saying that all this is going on the server?  Unless you have VB6 installed on the server, I doubt you'll be able to debug (let's just say really difficult to pull off).

Comment: I'm running the web site on my local web server on my machine.  The machine also has VB6 installed on it as well.

Comment: So go ahead and try to debug it then.